# Can only execute script one time

Tags: javascript, ajax, issuu

I'm using Ajax to load a page, and on that page I'm loading an external script from `issuu.com`. It works very nicely the first time either I or Ajax load the page, but if Ajax loads a new page and then goes back again it will not run the external script again (It loads the script, but doesn't execute it).

This is the page: http://dymak-corporate.134.lait.dk/catalogue/

You can see in e.g. the network tab of your browser's dev tools that it loads the script both times, but only executes the first time.

I have tried to load and execute the script in every way I can think of and nothing is working.

jQuery GetScript:

```
 $.getScript("//e.issuu.com/embed.js")
```

Ajax load the script and eval it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/scripts/embed.js",
    success: function (responseText) {
        eval(responseText);
    }
});
```

Adding it to the header every time and removing it before I add it:

```
$('#issuuScript').remove();
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.id = "issuuScript";
s.src = "//e.issuu.com/embed.js";
document.head.append(s);
```

Reloading it at every load:

```
function reload_js(src) {
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    $('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
}
reload_js('/scripts/embed.js');
```

I also tried adding it inline, without success.

Comment: Issuu has actually updated their embed scripts to also support dynamically created embeds. You should be able to succeed with your original approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how JavaScript is supposed to work. A file include is not a like a function call, but you are treating it like a function call.

How you should think about it:

I want to call `some_module.some_function()`. Is `some_module` loaded?

**No.** Load the file that has the module, then execute the function.

**Yes.** Just execute the function.

Comment: I would like to execute it like a function if i could, but it is a self invoking anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using the iframe implementation from issuu